# 2n3904/2n3906 driving mosfet gate

Tags: gate-driving, push-pull

[image: circuit]

I'm building a MOSFET driver like this. The signal source is 7V peak-to-peak. Vcc is 12V. The push-pull stage is 2n3904/2n3906.

I've tested the push-pull output before adding the transformer, and using a 50 ohm load, the output voltage is reduced by half, so I concluded that the output resistance of the push-pull stage is 50 ohm.

Then according to the MOSFET spec (IRF740), C_iss = 1400pF, at 13.5MHz I calculated the impedance to be 8 ohm. So I used a 2:1 transformer (therefore 4:1 impedance transformation) to match the load at the gate.

But now I get a flat signal at the Q3 gate, AC is almost non-existent. If I disconnect the MOSFET Q3, I get a good sine-wave. Can anybody help me find out what's the problem with this circuit?

C2 is a 104 capacitor which is practically a short at RF. The 2n3904 has a spec of peak 200mA current capacity, which I translate to be 2.5V for 1/4 period, which should get doubled by the transformer and is supposed to be enough to charge the gate to a observable voltage.

Comment: For completeness you might want to mention what C1 is and the frequency of your sine signal.

Comment: drain **and** source connected to ground.

Comment: I mentioned the 13.5MHz signal. The signal source is a Pierce oscillator using a 2n2222. C1 is also 104 cap, which is 0.1uF ceramic.

Comment: Drain are connected to ground for testing purpose. Is that a problem? I could float the drain or connect the drain to Vcc with a 1k Ohm but neither fixes the problem.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What happens to the drive signal at the bases when you connect the MOSFET gate? The current gain of those transistors won't be much at 13MHz, maybe 20, so you're loading the oscillator output with < 1K.

Comment: To drive the MOSFET for a Class-E amplifier to excite plasma in a vacuum chamber.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Without the MOSFET, 2n390x base is a sine wave between 0V and 6V; with the MOSFET connected, the base becomes  a non-symmetrical saw-shaped wave between 5V to 7V.

What's going on here?  What do you mean by loading the oscilator output with <1K and should I use a different kind of transistor pair?

Comment: The transformer is a Minicircuits RF transformer or something like that?

Comment: I am excited. Did you simulate your circuit? I just tried it for fun and found at the gate a ~4.8kHz ~4.2Vpp sine with a ~1.3Vpp 13.5MHz "peaks" modulated on it. Is that what you are seeing? Maybe post some pics... You know, the gate "consumes" some current and has some parasitic properties, thats probably what is leading to this. Putting a 10p or so before the gate might help

Comment: Okay 5-7V means that you've got only about 1V of signal left (subtract two Vbe drops), so you need more power gain.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The transformer is a toroid-wound twisted enamelled wire.

So, what happens is that the current gain is small, and the signal source can't output enough current, therefore it cannot charge the gates quickly enough, so the gate voltage remains small and drags the base voltage low, is that correct?

What would be a good way to get the power gain required? Could you suggest some topology?

Comment: @PlasmaHH I'm not getting even 500mV on the gates, I'm guessing Spehro is right about the power being too low.

Comment: For digital (square wave drive), a gate driver chip such as Micrel [MIC4420](http://www.micrel.com/_PDF/mic4420.pdf), for a video amplifier such as MAX9650. Both are cheap. An Apex power amplifier would be better again, but $$$.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I'm trying to avoid the gate drive IC completely, though I'm pretty new to RF circuits and have only a little experience on amplifiers.

I'm hoping to use a sine wave to drive the gate, using only discrete components. It seems my signal is too weak, should I google for 'current buffer'?

Comment: I'm only just aiming to get a RF power of 10W, or even 5W is enough.

Comment: What are the primary and leakage inductances of the transformer, and its self resonant frequency? Do you know if you are anywhere near saturating it?

Comment: Start simple. Leave out T1 and Q3. Load the output at C2 with the equivalent RC of Q3 gate. That way you don't worry about T1 and Q3 now. Expect to need a class AB bias for Q1/Q2. With the bases tied together there is a dead spot in the emitter drive will be killer at 13 MHz. Don't do any of this on a protoboard. Physical layout of all the parts and routes will be very important ... keep all loop areas as small as possible.

Answer (score 1):

To fully turn on an IRF740 it needs about 7V on the Gate. You have 7Vpp available, but using AC coupling cuts the usable voltage down to only 3.5V. Since the IRF740 doesn't even *start* to turn on until about 3.7V, you won't get anything out of it.

If you want to drive the FET with AC then you need to step the voltage *up* (not down) by about 2:1. Alternatively you could use a 1:1 transformer and apply a bias of about 3.5V to the 'cold' side of its secondary winding, raising the DC Gate voltage voltage above ground to make use of the full 7Vpp. Or you might be able to simply DC couple your push-pull driver to the FET.

> I get a flat signal at the Q3 gate, AC is almost non-existent. If I
>   disconnect the MOSFET Q3, I get a good sine-wave.

Have you measured the output impedance of your oscillator? My guess is that it is quite high, so the voltage collapses when a load is applied. You may need another stage of amplification to provide a low impedance rf source. Most rf transmitters rated for 5~10W have at least two stages of power amplification between the oscillator and final output.

> The 2n3904 has a spec of peak 200mA current capacity, which I translate to be 2.5V for 
>   1/4 period,

It might be able to take such abuse, but above 100mA its gain collapses so it won't provide the impedance reduction you need. You should treat the 200mA rating as an *absolute maximum*, not normal operating current. You need transistors that can deliver 800mA or more while still providing a reasonable current gain.